# Merge Json results into one

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code in a controller, as you can see it returns an object serialized to Json.

```
...
     [HttpGet("{id}")]
            public IActionResult Get(string id)
            {
                ClientsRepository ClientsRepo = new ClientsRepository(connectionString);
                return Json(ClientsRepo.GetClientCreditSummary(id));
            }
...
```

The method where it gets the data is in a ClientsRepo.GetClientCreditSummary, and I would like to merge it with another one called ClientsRepo.GetClient, and return it as a Json result in this same controller action.

How can I do that?

Comment: By merge what exactly do you mean? Are those 2 pieces of data the same type? What kind of structure do you want to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type:

```
return Json(new { ClientCreditSummary = ClientsRepo.GetClientCreditSummary(id), Client = ClientsRepo.GetClient(id) });
```

For more on anonymous types http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/anonymous-types-in-C-Sharp/

If you're instead wanting to merge the fields of the two entities into one entity, I think the best way would be to manually map each field into the new entity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very good form to take two object like that and mush together into one.

Consider instead making a new object that holds the other two as properties:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")] 
public IActionResult Get(string id
{
    var repo = new ClientsRepository(connectionString);
    var creditSummary = repo.GetClientCreditSummary(id);

    var client = repo.GetClientById(id);

    var result = new
    {
        Client = client,
        CreditSummary = creditSummary
    };

    return Json(result); 
}
```